# Get data from JSP to android with GSON

Tags: android, jsp, android-activity, gson, http-get

I have 2 activities for getting data from .jsp file to android device. I´m using GSON for this. My project includes the gson library. The problem is, when I start the activity, the application fails down, and shows me: Unfortunately, the application stopped.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView capitalTextView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        capitalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capital_textview);

        this.retrieveCapitals();
    }

    void retrieveCapitals() {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Please wait...", "Retrieving data...", true, true);

        CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask task = new CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new CancelListener(task));       
    }

    private class CapitalsRetrieverAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Response response;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.3:8080/Dochadzka/jsp/Android/GSON.jsp";

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                    return null;
                }

                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
                Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream);

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Country country : this.response.data) {

                builder.append(String.format("<br>Country: <b>%s</b><br>Capital: <b>%s</b><br><br>", country.getCountry(), country.getCapital()));

            }

            capitalTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

    }

    private class CancelListener implements OnCancelListener {

        AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> cancellableTask;

        public CancelListener(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
            cancellableTask = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            cancellableTask.cancel(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Response.java:

```
public class Response {

    ArrayList<Country> data;

    public Response() {
        data = new ArrayList<Country>();
    }

}
```

And my jsp file is:

```
{"data":
   [
     {"country":"Angola", "capital": "Luanda"},
     {"country":"Botswana", "capital": "Gaborone"},
     {"country":"Democratic Republic of the Congo", "capital": "Kinshasa"},
     {"country":"Lesotho", "capital": "Maseru"},
     {"country":"Madagascar", "capital": "Antananarivo"},
     {"country":"Malawi", "capital": "Lilongwe"},
     {"country":"Mauritius", "capital": "Port Louis"},
     {"country":"Mozambique", "capital": "Maputo"},
     {"country":"Namibia", "capital": "Windhoek"},
     {"country":"South Africa", "capital": "Pretoria"},
     {"country":"Swaziland", "capital": "Lobamba"},
     {"country":"Tanzania", "capital": "Dodoma"},
     {"country":"Zambia", "capital": "Lusaka"},
     {"country":"Zimbabwe", "capital": "Harare"}   
   ]
 }
```

Here is the error_log:
http://pastebin.com/K5Qjh6h4

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson`

GSON is not getting packaged and deployed with your project.

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary) for instructions on how to add it to your project.

Comment: it's on the build path in eclipse but that doesn't mean it'll be included in the package you are going to distribute. Follow the directions to get it into your deployable package

Comment: where can i get this instructions? I have the gson library in my build path and in folder **lib**.

Comment: i found the solution: i updated the gson libraries to the newest, after this i cleaned the project and then the project works :)

Comment: I linked to the instructions in the answer just in case you need any further information.